# Function is causing on page video to not load and cant seem to delay

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a troll page that plays a video in the background then goes through an endless alertbox loop

My code

```
</div><video autoplay="true" class="StretchtoFit" id="lol" loop="true">
<source src="./stream.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

<script>
function show_alert(){
    alert("Enjoy the stream");
    alert(show_alert().repeat(0));
}
show_alert();
</script>
```

The issue is that the function is called before the video loads and therefore doesnt play. when I try to add a delay to the function it causes the video to cutout almost immediately. My goal is for it to play the video in the background and have the alertbox loop going.

Comment: You want an alert box to keep showing. Way to annoy the Client. I don't know why you got downvoted, though. The question is clear, but the video is playing before the alert. `alert()` may stop processes, depending on the Browser.

Comment: It a joke with friends

Comment: What's with that `.repeat()`? Your `show_alert()` function does not return a String, it just does an `alert()`. Even if `alert()` did return a String `.repeat(0)` gives you `''`.

Answer (score 0):

From [Google Chromium Policies](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/dialogs-policy) :

> While they fit into the JavaScript of the time, their **synchronous** API
>   is problematic for modern browsers. Because the **JavaScript engine**
>   **needs to pause** until a user response is obtained, the JavaScript
>   dialogs are app-modal. And because the dialogs are app-modal, they
>   commonly (and unfortunately) are used to harm our users.
>
> Because of this, the Chromium team highly recommends that you not use
>   JavaScript dialogs.

Basically, since the alert box blocks every other code bits while it is shown, the stream cannot be run.